# $d(A,B) \le d(x,A) + d(x,B)$

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A,B\subseteq X$ subsets, $x\in X$. Then
>   $$
> d(A,B) \le d(x,A) + d(x,B).
> $$

I have an attempt below but just don't feel it's correct and want some feedback.

*Let $t\in A, s\in B$. Then
$$
d(t,s) \le d(t,x) + d(s,x) \\
\therefore d(t,s) - d(t,x) \le d(s,x)
$$
and
$$
d(A,B) - d(t,x) \le d(t,s) - d(t,x) \\ 
\therefore d(A,B) - d(t,x) \le d(s,x). 
$$ 
Once the last inequality stands for all $s\in B$, we have
$$
d(A,B) - d(t,x) \le \inf\{d(s,x)|s\in B\} = d(x,B),
$$
then
$$
d(A,B) - d(x,B) \le d(t,x)
$$
for all $t\in A$. Accordingly,
$$
d(A,B) - d(x,B) \le \inf\{d(t,x)|t\in A\} = d(x,A),
$$
and it follows.*

Comment: I think $t\in A, s\in A$ is already not what you inted

Comment: Note: Given $\epsilon>0$, there exist $a\in A$, $b\in B$ with $d(x,a)<d(x,A)+\epsilon$ and $d(x,b)<d(x,B)+\epsilon$. Then $d(A,B)\le d(a,b)\le \ldots$

Comment: It's $t\in A, s\in B$, thanks.